# html5 pattern match for some words

Tags: regex, html, pattern-matching

I'm working with form validation and want to use pattern attribute for validate the input field. The field has the following criteria:

1. It should be minimum 2 characters in length
2. It can not be only space
3. It can not contains some common words like `of`, `for`, `the` ect. (case-insensitive match)

So what should be the exact pattern RegEx for that. I'm trying with the following code but not works?

```
<input type="text" 
       pattern="^/[^of|for|the]/i$" 
       title="Avoid words like: of, for, the">
```

Comment: You mistake character classes for groups. You should not pass delimiters to HTML5 pattern attribute. Try `(?!.*\b(?:[Oo][Ff]|[fF][Oo][Rr]|[Tt][hH][Ee])\b)(?!\s+$).{2,}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistake character classes for groups. You should not pass delimiters to HTML5 pattern attribute.

Also note that since you cannot pass flags/modifiers with the regex, you have to use character classes like `[oO]` to match `o` in a case-insensitive way.

Also, the pattern is anchored, that is, placed inside `(?:...)`, thus, no need to use anchors around the pattern.

Use

```
(?!.*\b(?:[Oo][Ff]|[fF][Oo][Rr]|[Tt][hH][Ee])\b)(?!\s+$).{2,}
```